# How to upload image using ckeditor in django?

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = RichTextUploadingField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', views.logout, name='logout', kwargs={'next_page': '/'}),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
]
# serving media files only on debug mode
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT
        }),
    ]
```

I will upload image using CKeditor.
There is no error.
However, it looks like a picture.

[image: pic]

Comment: So what's the question about ?

Answer (score 0):

When rendering html in templates, make sure you mark it as safe...

```
{{ article.text|safe }}
```

See documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#safe